# What to look for in a microphone/studio

Tags: microphone, foley, purchase-advice, low-budget

So, I know this question will probably be really far-fetched.  However, I was wondering what I should look for in a low-budget microphone for making video game sound effects, as well as a studio.  When I say "decent in cost", I likely mean less than $50, but I could stretch that a little if necessary.  The lower, the better.

For example:

Is stereo or mono better?
Should I use a portable voice recorder?
Are there any brands that are decent in cost and have a good quality?
Are there any types of sounds that are better to be made on the computer (JFXR/Audacity)?

As far as my studio:

Should I put up sound absorbers?
Or should I use sound diffusers?
Or a mix of both?
Does it need to be a large or small room?
My current plan is to refurbish an old tree house.  Would there be any complications with this?

Of course, if there are any other questions/important facts that I am missing, please let me know.  Thank you!

Comment: This could be split into a few different questions and then they might get better traction.

Comment: Keto - as DoritoStyle said, we try to keep to single questions, as each can then be answered. If you have a browse around, you will see that most of your questions have already been answered here.

Answer (score 1):

These are really broad questions. In terms of a mic. At $50 your in the Chinese unbranded territory type of microphone and most (I would imagine) couldn't give you an opinion on one that would be worthwhile. You really need to be in the $200 range before your getting into worthy entry level. I would look for a second hand bargain on eBay. Maybe old sm57 or something similar if you budget is that tight.

In summary there are reasons why you would record in stereo and mono and there are reasons why you would use diffusers and absorbers. Too much to explain here.

For the kind of questions your asking I'd really recommend reading some beginner to intermediate books on sound. Rick Viers book on sound recording is very good. It leans more toward location sound but he talks a lot about Sound theory and microphones in a way anyone could understand. He's also a Sound designer.